# Get amount of active user of the last n days grouped by date

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

Suppose I have a Hive table `logins` with the following columns:

```
user_id | login_timestamp
```

I'm now interested in getting some activity KPIs. For instance, daily active user:

```
SELECT 
to_date(login_timestamp) as date,
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) daily_active_user
FROM
logins
GROUP BY to_date(login_timestamp)
ORDER BY date asc
```

Changing it from daily active to weekly/monthly active is not a great deal because I can just exchange the `to_date()` function to get the month and then group by that value.

What I now want to get is the distinct amount of user who were active in the last n days (e.g. 3) grouped by date. Additionally, what I'm looking for is a solution that works for a variable time window and not only for one day (getting the amount of active user of the last 3 days on day x only would be easy).

The result is supposed to like somewhat like this:

```
date, 3d_active_user
2017-12-01, 111
2017-12-02, 234
2017-12-03, 254
2017-12-04, 100
2017-12-05, 103
2017-12-06, 103
2017-12-07, 230
```

Using a subquery in the first select (e.g. `select x, (select max(x) from x) as y from z`) building a workaround for the moving time window is not possible because it is not supported by the Hive version I'm using.

I tried my luck something like `COUNT(DISTINCT IF(DATEDIFF(today,login_date)<=3,user_id,null))` but everything I tried so far is not working.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can user "BETWEEN" function. 
If you want to find the active users, log in from the particular date to till now.

`SELECT to_date(login_timestamp) as date,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) daily_active_user 
FROM logins
WHERE login_timestamp BETWEEN startDate_timeStamp AND now() 
GROUP BY to_date(login_timestamp) 
ORDER BY date asc`

If you want the active users, who are log in users for specific date range then:
NOTE:-

`SELECT to_date(login_timestamp) as date,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) daily_active_user 
FROM logins
WHERE login_timestamp BETWEEN to_date(startDate_timeStamp) AND to_date(endDate_timeStamp) 
GROUP BY to_date(login_timestamp) 
ORDER BY date asc`

Comment: I guess your second approach would work when setting a fixed start/end date. However, I specifically don't want to do this in order to be able to get the statistics for more than one day in one query.